# Pull from an array every 3 days.. time iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, activerecord

I'm setting up a rails API, that I want to `pop` from an array every 3 days (72 hours). I'm a little lost how to iterate through dates to correctly select from my array.  Here's what I'm currently working with.

```
def index
  theme = ["Superhero", "Star-Wars", "Pokemon", "Other-Animals", "Hats", "Sports"]
  current_theme = theme.shuffle.pop
  start_time = DateTime.new(2017,5,9,00,00)
  end_time = DateTime.new(2018,5,9,00,00)

  start_time.upto(end_time) do |t|
    cycle = t*3
    while t = cycle do 
      render json: current_theme
      // bad loop 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is the array static or is it dynamic? If it's dynamic, you probably want to store it in a database with a date stamp or some mechanism of determine which record you want. Consider the scenario where your app crashed and restarted. Would you need to recreate that list or would you want it to be stored somewhere?

Comment: Stumbled across this issue shortly after the fix, I set up the shuffle in the seed file instead, so the array is now static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `.cycle`, `.step` and `.next` all from [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html)

```
require 'date'
start_time = DateTime.new(2017,5,9,00,00)
end_time = DateTime.new(2018,5,9,00,00)

# create an enumerator
theme = ["Superhero", "Star-Wars", "Pokemon", "Other-Animals", "Hats", "Sports"].cycle

# iterate using step over 3 days
start_time.step(end_time, 3) do |date|
    puts "#{date} - #{theme.next}"
    # Do something like this:
    render json: theme if DateTime.now.beginning_of_day <= date + 2
end
# => 2017-05-09T00:00:00+00:00 - Superhero
# => 2017-05-12T00:00:00+00:00 - Star-Wars
# => 2017-05-15T00:00:00+00:00 - Pokemon
# => 2017-05-18T00:00:00+00:00 - Other-Animals
# => 2017-05-21T00:00:00+00:00 - Hats
# => 2017-05-24T00:00:00+00:00 - Sports
# => 2017-05-27T00:00:00+00:00 - Superhero
#...
```

Also `DateTime.now.beginning_of_day` depends on ActiveSupport but you can easily implement something similar,  `Date.today.to_datetime` etc

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `cronjob` for this kind of operations. [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) is a great gem that creates and updates `crontab` with Ruby DSL. For example you can write your task as simple as:

```
every 3.days do
  # some code to be execute
end
```

Comment: I had the whatever gem working, but I'm trying to push this to heroku, which doesn't accept the whatever gem, and I had bad luck with the alternative scheduler gem. Thank you! Great solution without heroku

Comment: I think you can create a rake task and use [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#scheduling-jobs).